# MySQL count(*) only counts the first row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The table 'servers' consists of information about some minecraft servers and some of the information is how many players there are currently online, (that row is called "Players") what i want to do is to count how many players there are on all of the servers on that table, so i do

```
$rt = mysql_query("SELECT Players, COUNT(*) FROM servers") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rt);
if ($row) {
    echo $row[0];
}
```

but for some reson those few lines of code only return the number of online players from 1 server, instead of all of the 14 servers
 
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Players hold the number of people? Do you want ALL of them total? If so, it would be

```
SELECT SUM(Players) FROM servers
```

If you want it grouped by server

```
SELECT SUM(Players), id FROM servers GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is actually returning a 2D array, Try

```
print_r($row);
```

You will see the difference. But i strongly recommend you to use

```
SELECT SUM(Players) FROM servers
```

That way you will just get the count.

Comment: +1 for explaining what he was doing wrong instead of just providing answer

Comment: I strongly believe that teaching fishing to a person is more valuable than giving him a fish. :)

Answer (score 0):

in order for count to make sense you need a GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT 
    Players, count(*)
FROM 
    servers
GROUP BY Players
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add each Players value to your result

```
SELECT SUM(Players) FROM Servers
```